# Error debugging in a MVC View: The following breakpoint cannot be set

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013

There's no real code example to show since it will happen no matter where you put the breakpoint.

Using Visual Studio 2013 (we migrated this project from 2012), I get this error when setting a breakpoint in any .cshtml View:

```
The following breakpoint cannot be set
```

I've tried various things such as cleaning my solution, closing and opening VS2013, and others. Nothing seems to work.

What can I do about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We found this node in our site's root `Web.config`:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" assemblyPostProcessorType="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.Common.AspPerformanceInstrumenter, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.AspNetHelper, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
```

Lo and behold, removing the `assemblyPostProcessorType` attribute solved the issue. It should look like this after the fix:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
```

Hope this helps somebody else. It was driving my boss crazy...